# How transactions are broadcasted to Block Producers?

Tags: transactions, dpos, net-plugin

When a transaction is initiated and send by a user, how are these transactions broadcasted to Block Producers?

Answer (score 2):

Each Node in the Network adds a list of peers it communicates with to exchange data.

When a transaction is sent to a node, it is passed on to the peers and this way broadcasted to the entire network of producers.